# Why size of c++ dynamic array is not changed?

Tags: c++

Hi guys I tested c++ dynamic array and I changed  2 inputs every time.
but array size is not changed. Why?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int r = 0;
int c = 0;
int cnt = 1;

cin >> r;
cin >> c;

int** arr1 = new int* [r];


for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
{
    arr1[i] = new int[c];
}

cout << sizeof(arr1) << endl;
cout << sizeof(arr1[0]);
}
```

> I knew that If I entered two value 3 and 4 then results are 3 and 4

> but the results are 4 and 4

Comment: `sizeof` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Unrelated: You should probably use a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Note: variable length array is not C++ standard.

Comment: Oh .. That is interesting. Thank you guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are testing the size of a *pointer* which is always 4 on 32 bit.
That's because `sizeof` is a compile time thing; it cannot determine an array size.

Generally arrays do not carry size information, that is why functions like `strlen` need a null terminator.

Suggestion: use `std::vector`.

Comment: To add to this answer, you should debug your program put a break point after your for loop. Modern IDEs will let you see each variable being used and its values/e,element. While vector is a great option, because you have the sizes input, just keep those handy whenever you need the size of the array

Comment: @Michael Chourdakis  Thank you Thank you so much